# Using custom Java annotation in pom.xml with failsave

Tags: java, annotations, pom.xml, java-failsafe

I created a custom Java annotation

```
@Tag("webservice")
public @interface WebserviceTest {
    boolean executeAndIgnoreCondition() default false;
}
```

Furthermore I created Java test with this annotation. Now I would like to run failsave but only tests with my annotation 'WebserviceTest' should be tested.

I tried a lot but nothing was ok.
My last example:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>
                            integration-test
                        </goal>
                        <goal>
                            verify
                        </goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
                    <groups>webservice</groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If I annotate my tests with

```
@Tag("webservice")
```

everything is fine but I need to annotate my test with @WebserviceTest. How does it work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have nothing found in the junit documentation that `@Tag` can be used as a meta annotation like your are doing it here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. You have to add

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

to the annotation